# Cant start nor stop httpd

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd

```
[root@ap-dcr-splm53 ~]# su - x3ds
[x3ds@ap-dcr-splm53 ~]$ service httpd start
Starting httpd: (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]
:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
[x3ds@ap-dcr-splm53 ~]$ su - root
Password:
[root@ap-dcr-splm53 ~]# cd /var/run/httpd
[root@ap-dcr-splm53 httpd]# ls
[root@ap-dcr-splm53 httpd]#
```

I am trying to start `httpd`, but it wouldn't allow me. I tried to find the file `httpd.pid` but it doesn't show me although it exists. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to start the daemon as a non-root user. Trying to bind to port numbers 1024 and less require root.

Try starting the service as root:

```
sudo service httpd start
```